# XPath Query - Return attribute with same element that was used to filter

Tags: xml, xpath

First post here, though I have received lots of helpful information from this site before.

I am trying to use google sheets to concatenate API queries, and return specific data.

The problem I am running into is being able to filter using a specific attribute and then return another attribute that is within the same element.

```
<schedules>
  <schedule stationId="12345" date="2018-11-15">
    <event progId="PR123456789" time="9:00">
        <quals>live</quals>
    </event>
  </schedule>
</schedules>
```

I want to filter to a specific time and then return the `progId`.

I have tried seemingly every combination of XPath query and at this point I think it's not possible without some google appscript wizardry, but I am happy to be proven wrong.

```
//event/[@time="9:00"]/@TMSId
//event[@time="9:00" and @TMSId]
//event[@time="9:00"]/@TMSId
//event[@time=9:00]/@TMSId
//event[@time=9:00]@TMSId
```

I feel like there has to be something simple I am missing.

```
//event/@progId
```

The code above returns all of the program IDs successfully. However I need to filter the output to a specific time.

Comment: Sorry folks, answered my own question.

I had a typo in the time, time in API query has a leading 0, which I didn't account for. 

The correct query to return attributes of the same element would be as detailed below:

//event[@time="09:00"]/@progId

Then to retrieve just the first one I had to use an index function surrounding my importXml query. 

=index(IMPORTXML(Y2,L2),1)

Thanks all :-) Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Clear question everything is well organized, code and as well as question section. at the end you've find your owns problem's solution in the comments section. you've learned to your this site in your very first post... Thumbs up for you. as I Upvoted both your question and comment.

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
//event[@time=9:00]/@progId
```

give you?

Comment: In my case it give me #NA because my time in the API output was actually 09:00. I forgot to include the leading 0 in my formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
//event[@time='9:00']/@progId
```

It should give you the desired value.